Density in the real line
Let $E=\left\{\dfrac{a}{b}~\mid~(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}^*~a~\text{is odd}~~\text{and}~b~~\text{is even}\right\}$. We have th show that $E$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x<y$, we have $2(x-\dfrac{1}{2})<2(y-\dfrac{1}{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so:
$$\exists(p,q)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}^*,~ gcd(p,q)=1,~~2(x-\dfrac{1}{2})<\dfrac{p}{q}<2(y-\dfrac{1}{2})$$
Then $x<\dfrac{p+q}{2q}<y$
if $p$ odd and $q$ even, we can acheive our result (Same thing when $p$ even and $q$ odd)
but i can't have the answer when $p$ and $q$ are odd integers. Can you please help me with this question.
Thank you for your help

Did you mean $E = {\frac ab\mid (a,b)\in \mathbb Z\times \mathbb N^*, gcd(a,b) = 1, ...}$?

Let $q\in\Bbb N$ be a strict upper bound for $\frac1{y-x}$, i.e. $q(y-x)>1$. Then, the interval $(2qx,2qy)$ has length $>2$ hence contains at least one odd integer $a$, so
$$x<\frac a{2q}<y\quad\text{and}\quad\frac a{2q}\in E.$$

Thank you for your help

Edit: I rewrite my answer because I realized that the -\frac{1}{2} is unnecessary.
I'm sure there are other more elegant ways to do this, but let's use something similar to your method here.
Let $x, y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x < y$, as you said,
$$\exists (x, y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}^*, 2x<\frac{p}{q}<2y$$
Now, choose $t$ such that $\frac{1}{tq} < 2y - \frac{p}{q}$. Let $p' = tp$ and $q' = tq$. We now have
$$2x<\frac{p'}{q'}<2y$$
and
$$2x<\frac{p' + 1}{q'}<2y$$
Therefore
$$x<\frac{p'}{2q'}<y$$
and
$$x<\frac{p'+ 1}{2q'}<y$$
This gives us the desired result since one of $p'$ and $p'+1$ must be odd. Hope this helps.

Did you mean p' and q' everytime you mention "p" and "q" after "Therefore, we have"?

Oh yeah I'm sorry

I have fixed it

@YuankunZou thank you for your help.
